# Can I use the DetailsView control without binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I wanna use the `DetailsView` control without binding it with a datasource (just in insert mode) but the problem is when I try to get the values of the fields throught `ItemInserting` event handler I found the `e.Values` property empty however there are some fields.

**Note**: I wanna use it (The `DetailsView` control) *[instead of allign the fields manually]* because there're already a theme for it in whole the system and I don't want to do that again from scratch for custom template.

Any Idea !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah yes, I wrote a blog post on this topic. http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2008/12/12/getting-your-data-out-of-the-data-controls.aspx.

BTW in .NET 4.0 e.Values won't be empty :).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this solution didn't extract  `TemplateField` fields, Any help!!

Comment: It should, what issue are you having?

Comment: It's done. thatnks a lot but the values isn't extracted in the Update. they're work well in Insert only.